# i18next-ko and multiple namespaces

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, i18next

I am using this wrapper https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-ko for i18next to combine it with knockout js. It basically works great, but I have encountered a problem: i need to have two translations in the same time, like for example: app interface in your natural language where you prepare documents (ex. invoices) in some another language. I'm not really sure how to achieve that. Should I have two instances of i18next with two different data stores?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the namespaces functionality? https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces.html

if it's just about multiple languages - you can pass `lng` in options to access translations in different language.

But honestly i'm not to deep into the ko bindings...just maintain i18next.

Comment: I don't know how could i use namespace functionality even though there is nothing about supporting that in ko wrapper. Let's assume I have a worker who is in England and he would like to have English interface of application, however he is preparing special kind of document for worker in Spain and would like to see how this document will look like in his language. This might seem a bit ridiculous, but that's a real issue here :)

Comment: https://www.i18next.com/api.html#getfixedt -> all possible with i18next - how much the API is supported more depends on knockout wrapper - which i don't know as i never used knockout. But using different namespace is rather easy by prefixing key with `myNamespace:`

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot, seems like i'll have to figure it out how to get it with the wrapper.